# executing a node js child process after click html button

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs

i have to design a simple webpage. that was click the Button then the command prompt will be open.
this is my aim
Below i have to mention the html code and node js code.
**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p>guru</p>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Run"/>
    </form>    

</body></html>
```

the below code was node js **sample.js**

```
const express=require("express");
const bodyParser =require("body-parser");
const app=express();
const child_process=require('child_process');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine','ejs')
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('test');
});
app.post('/',function(req,res){
    res.render(
            child_process.exec("cmd.exe" ,(err,stdout,stderr)=>{
                process.stdout.write(stdout)
        })
    );
});
app.listen(8080);
console.log('listen');
```

after running the script i have faced the error:)

**TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object**

**give the suggestion**

Comment: wrong use of `res.render()` . Bring your `child_process.exec` out of `res.render()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a string to render.
Maybe you have to reverse the callback order to:

```
app.post('/',function(req,res){
   child_process.exec("cmd.exe" ,(err,stdout,stderr)=> {
     res.render(stdout)
    })
});
```